# R function to convert character statements to numeric in alphabetic order

Tags: r

I am trying to create a function that takes a character sentence and converts it into integer values that correspond to its placement in the alphabet (a=1, c=3, etc). From there I want to be able to input those values (integers) in a separate function that will spit out the statement again which will likely use letters() and LETTERS() functions.

```
x1 <- "Hello My Friend"

char_to_int <- function(x) {
vals <- strsplit(x, '')[[1]]
inds <- vals != ' '
vals[!inds] <- NA
vals[inds] <- match(tolower(vals[inds]), letters)
return(as.numeric(vals))
```

}

```
int_to_char <- function(x) {
vals <- letters(x)
paste0(tapply(vals, cumsum(is.na(vals)), 
        function(x) paste0(na.omit(x), collapse = ''), collapse = ' ')
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use these functions. For `char_to_int` I replace spaces in the text with `NA` so we get a numeric vector as an output.

```
x1 <- "Hello My Friend"

char_to_int <- function(x) {
  vals <- strsplit(x, '')[[1]]
  inds <- vals != ' '
  vals[!inds] <- NA
  vals[inds] <- match(tolower(vals[inds]), letters)
  return(as.numeric(vals))
}
#[1]  8  5 12 12 15 NA 13 25 NA  6 18  9  5 14  4
```

For `int_to_char` :

```
int_to_char <- function(x) {
  vals <- letters[x]
  tools::toTitleCase(paste0(tapply(vals, cumsum(is.na(vals)), 
            function(x) paste0(na.omit(x), collapse = '')), collapse = ' '))
}

int_to_char(char_to_int(x1))
#[1] "Hello My Friend"
```

Comment: Thanks, interesting way to do this. I like it. If I wanted the first letters output in my int_to_char function to be capital letters would much change? So the h, m, and f, being capital letters.

Comment: @Minoo We can use `tools::toTitleCase` for it. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more comprehensive approach that retains spaces and also allows for special characters. (char_to_int approach won't be robust to non-alphanumeric characters). My approach also takes care of returning a string of numbers separated by a character which I call num_sep.
Both functions, again for robustness need a special argument, num_sep which will make the coded sentence readable. For decoding too, this argument will be essential.

Here you go :

```
letter_to_num<-function(string,num_sep){
  all_letters<-c(letters,LETTERS)
  num_seq<-c(1:26,1:26)
  ref_table<-matrix(c(all_letters,num_seq),ncol = 2)

  splitted<-strsplit(string,"")[[1]]
  alpha_coded <-ref_table[match(splitted,ref_table[,1]),2]
  alpha_coded[is.na(alpha_coded)] <- splitted[is.na(alpha_coded)]
  return(paste0(alpha_coded,collapse = num_sep))
  
  }



num_to_letter<-function(coded_string,num_sep){
  all_letters<-c(letters,LETTERS)
  num_seq<-c(1:26,1:26)
  ref_table<-matrix(c(all_letters,num_seq),ncol = 2)
  
  splitted<-strsplit(coded_string,num_sep)[[1]]
  num_decoded <- ref_table[match(splitted,ref_table[,2]),1]
  num_decoded[is.na(num_decoded)] <- splitted[is.na(num_decoded)]
  return(paste0(num_decoded,collapse = ""))
  
  
  
}

special_example<-"Hello My Friend!!!!@@"
coded<-letter_to_num(string=special_example,num_sep = "-") 


#"8-5-12-12-15- -13-25- -6-18-9-5-14-4-!-!-!-!-@-@"

decoded<-num_to_letter(coded,num_sep = "-")
#"hello my friend!!!!@@"
```